# What is Ubuntu's equivalent of an exe file?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

Sometimes I want to install a program when offline. But `apt-get` downloads as you install.

Is there a way to install a program, like you would install a `.exe`, on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes you can. Instead of a .exe file it is a .deb file.

Comment: @Tim please explain how to do? I am a newbie as mentioned in the original question...

Comment: @karel http://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line may be better

Comment: @Tim I think you missed the target.

Comment: @karel he wants ubuntu's exe equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
apt-get install -d
```

To download software and dependencies without installing them. The .deb files (pretty much equivalent to Windows .exe installers), are then downloaded to `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

Unless you've issued `apt-get clean` pretty much anything you've ever installed via apt-get should have the .deb files stored there.

Also you can install the .deb files via `dpgk -i` but you have to remember to install the dependencies (and their dependencies and so on), first. Or you should also just be able to double click a .deb file in your file browser and Software Center should take care of it for you.

For example: I want to install `gedit` (which is included with Ubuntu normally so it won't download tons of dependency .deb files). But I have a system that, for whatever reason, doesn't have gedit and has no internet connect.

So first, on a computer connected to the internet, I run `apt-get install --reinstall -d gedit` (because if you try running `apt-get install -d gedit` on a system with gedit already installed to the latest version it just tells you it is already installed), which then goes through the normal process of downloading the package (in this case there are no dependencies), and then stops.

[image: Running apt-get install --reinstall -d gedit]

Then I locate the file under `/var/cache/apt/archives/` ...

[image: /var/cache/apt/archives/]

... and move it to the computer which needs gedit installed and install it, in this case using the Software Center.

[image: Installing with Software Center]

Or I could install it using `cd /var/cache/apt/archives` and `dpkg -i gedit_3.10.4-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb`

Comment: Good answer :) Explaining how to then install these .deb file from command line or GUI would make it even better!

Comment: @Ian Lantzy  please give me an example.. :)

Comment: Alright give me a minute let me take some screenshots...

Comment: @IanLantzy Lovely to see a new user with a good answer! +1, and more if I could!

Comment: @MikeFriedman there are an infinite number of potential examples that could be used.  For instance, I could use `nginx` and `nginx-common` and `nginx-core` or similar as examples if my system needed an offline method to install the NGINX web server.  Essentially, it's impossible to create 'one example' that would work everywhere.  The tricky part is because of dependencies - a lot of 'regularly used' Desktop programs have a *lot* of dependencies that you would also have to download.

Comment: @IanLantzy Thanks for helping me out. I really appreciate it. I just can't upvote you as my reputation is not high. I would request you to upvote my question so that in future I can appreciate anyone for helping me or for making an useful question/answer to anyone.